# SharePoint 2010 lists, libraries, other objects create button not work

Tags: silverlight

- I installed Microsoft SharePoint on my vmware.
- created new application and site collection serve for the url test.contoso.com.
- on my real machine I logged in to the url test.contoso.com and every thing was ok.
- but when I used to add new list I got the unhandled exception occurred in the SilverLight interface message on IE while that worked perfectly on Mozilla Firefox.
- I do my searches and try to enable and disable Web Page Security Validation but nothing changed.
- Finally I tried to disable SilverLight and use the plane web page to create a new list or library.
- I fill the information and try to create the list but shocked that the create button not work ... not response .

please any help or suggestions ...

Thanks for your time

Comment: IE version you using?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar  problem with IE 10.0

Try to remove IE 10 and revert to IE 9.0

that is most probably a bug Microsoft didn't fix (hopefully soon)

You can revert to IE by uninstalling the windows update that installed IE 10 (control panel )

Best of luck

Comment: thnx George, I'll try this ... I really appreciate it ^_^